# How do I delete a merge commit?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have done some mess in my repo, which I don't understand at all.

A strange commit has appeared:

> commit 70cc4bd585019286ef64ef591f1b6ab310484eb3 (HEAD, origin/master,
> origin/HEAD, master) Merge: 960b06a 709f964 Author: DuchSuvaa
> bga.sowa@gmail.com Date:   Tue Sep 12 15:46:05 2023 +0200
>
> ```
> Merge branch 'master' of https://github.com/DuchSuvaa/monitor-kolejek
> ```

I don't really understand how that happened. Someone told me that git reset --hard HEAD~1 will do the job but when I do it, I am checkouted to the third (!) commit from the end and nothing is removed from GitHub.

How do I remove that problematic merge commit from my repo on **Github**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `git log --oneline`
2. Copy the commit hash before merge one.
3. `git reset --hard <copied-commit-hash>`
4. `git push --force` (be carefully, it rewrites the remote history)

Comment: it checkouted to the right one (the second from the end) but that merge commit is still on server

Comment: Sorry, I edit my post.

Comment: Be careful with 3-4 steps if there are some other commits after merge one - you will lose them completely.

Comment: There is `git revert` as alternative

Answer (score 1):

Code is no change because you are working on local branch.

General, I divide 2 cases

1. if you didn't push code on remote repository

Because when we use git merge, it normally create a new commit on branch that was merge into, so we can use git reset to undo git merge. There are two ways to do that

if you have just commited, and you immediately perform that command

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

or, if you want to undo a command git merge in the past, you have to determine commit hash before git merge and perform

```
git reset --hard <commit-hash-before-merge>
```

2 you pushed code on remote repository

For rule, we never change git history of shared branch (branch was pushed). So, in that case, we can use git revert to create a new commit that help me back to  commit before merge.

The first, you have to determine commit hash of merge commit and run

```
git revert <commit hash merge> -m 1
```